# Pow() function in for loop in C

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why I can't do this?

It doesn't compile, I know that I gotta be wrong somehow.

I'm trying to print powers of 2 but I just can't do it this way.

Can anyone help me? This is the code I wrote. I'm using gcc on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    int power;

    printf("Powers of 2:\n");

    {int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            power = pow(2,i);
            printf("%s%i %s %i %s","2^",i,"=",power,"\n");

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to ask a good question: replace *It doesn't compile* to the actual compile error. And for the question, did you use `-lm`?

Comment: Everyone is having problem with pow :P

Answer (score 4):

`gcc foo.c -lm -o foo`

you have compile like this.
'm' is math lib

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine in xcode and gcc, but some compilers like older versions of xcode do not like not having a void in the int main() function. Also you do have a few excessive things in your code.

The bracket before the int declaration is pointless. Also your print statment looks crazy.
The same thing can be accomplished with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    int power, i;

    printf("Powers of 2:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        power = pow(2,i);
        printf("2^%i = %i\n",i,power);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Btw if you wanted to get really crazy, your print statment could be just
printf("2^%i = %.0f\n",i,pow(2,i));